# Filtering Large Lists with AND and OR operators

Tags: 2013, custom-list, filter, large-lists

I have a larger list of data including more than 5000 items.  Users create entries and assign them to managers for review.  Managers action the items and users re-review.  I am using SharePoint 2013 and I don't have SP designer access.

I have a dashboard view that has worked up till the 5000 limit.  All the columns I am using to filter are indexed.

The dashboard has 2 views of the list, one for unactioned items and one for actioned items.  The unactioned items should display any item created by you, or assigned to you from the last 60 days where the issue status is not "closed".  The actioned items list should show the same, except that issues status must equal "closed"

I feel like I have tried every combination of AND/OR I can think of.

```
Created >=  Today-60
and
Created by = Me
and 
Issue Status NOT closed
or 
Created >= Today-60
and 
Assigned to = Me
and 
Issue Status Not closed.
```

I've also tried

```
Assigned to = Me
or
Created by = Me
and 
Issue status not Closed
and
Created >= Today-60
```

I've tried a few other combinations too, but I either get zero results, or a 5000 item limit error.

In the interim I have created a 2nd dashboard for managers, but it would be great if I could get the main dashboard working for both user groups.

How do I setup the filter correctly to achieve the above with > 5000 items?

Answer (score 1):

**"You need to remove or increase the list view threshold."  Keep in mind that the 5000 limit exists for a reason.** It's a SQL limitation, not a SharePoint limitation. Increasing the limit have have a major performance impact on performance for other users. If you just have a few SharePoint users, or list this list is the primary use of your SharePoint farm, then experiment with changing this limit.

**Split the list:**

I'm guessing that most of this list's content is in the "actioned" category. Can these be moved into a folder, or into another list by using a workflow?

**If any of these columns types are used in your filter, then they cannot be indexed:**

- Multiple lines of text
- Choice (multi-valued)
- Calculated
- Hyperlink or Picture
- Custom Columns
- Person or Group (multi-valued) (Lookup)
- External data

**The order of your ANDs and ORs:**

Take a look at the following article to see how mixed ANDs and ORs are processed:

http://wss-essentials.blogspot.com/2009/12/sharepoint-view-filter-order-of.html

Comment: Hi Mike.  Thanks for the reply.  None of the columns I am using are included in your list above.  I opted to create a 2nd dashboard for my users.  One dashboard covers "created by" and the other covers "assigned to."  It's not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters on lists with over 5000 items if the columns that are used in filtering are indexed.  You need to remove or increase the list view threshold.  Then add each of the columns used in filtering, sorting, grouping, to the indexed columns for the list.  Then enable or decrease the list view threshold and test.

The list could also have the threshold permanently disabled then all views would work but there may be some performance issues.
Or the list view threshold of the web app could be permanently increased to say 10,000 to give you more time to work on a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  However all the columns included in the filters are already indexed.  So this doesn't appear to be the cause.  One of the columns was just indexed today, so I'm not sure if the indexing process is delayed and could be causing my issue?

Comment: Can you test each filter individually?  eg Created >= Today

Comment: Yes, if I filter for each of the above individually it they all return fewer than 5000 items and work.  Only when combined do I get the error.  Further to this, the using Created as today-60 should always return fewer than 5000 items, so if i filter for date first, the others should always work correctly.  The problem appears to be that SharePoint doesnt allow for differentiating the and/or statements into groups.  If I was able to construct Date and Status and (Assigned to OR Created by) it would be so simple...

Comment: Sometime in your views you need to repeat your filters.  something1 AND something2 OR something 1 AND something3 OR something1 AND something4